# Keyboard Extension Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, keyboard

I am building a custom keyboard extension (iOS 9+) and have found a more than annoying **memory leak**.

When leaving an application (in this test case the **Messages** app) then returning, this leak occurs. Typically(seen in the photos of **Xcode's Instruments7** below)

I have literally done nothing to the template but receive this leak. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?...

#### UPDATE

For fun, here's a screen shot of the glorious leak... **AND** first a snippet of my complex VC....

This is after tapping a text field, dismissing the controller, then tapping the field again

(show -> hide -> show)

```
#import "KeyboardViewController.h"

@implementation KeyboardViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I would like to have awarded the bounty to a solution, not the only answer I received... the answer to this really ended up being "Oops I'm not doing anything wrong...".

After having done way too deep of a dive investigating what *really* is causing these leaks (14 total after literally removing everything except the view controller's instance), I discovered the **true culprit.**

> **Apple**.

---

Even when I remove **ALL** code, literally leaving only the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Great...

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Super!

}
```

...I still get **14 leaks**, all of which are sprung from `UIKit`, `Foundation`, and `CoreFoundation`. Basically, if I removed anything else from the process, there would *be no process*, as nothing would be happening. Who knows...maybe the leak would still be there then too..

Nevertheless, thankfully this leak does NOT crush the memory allocation unless you intend to perhaps type a message for a few years straight. It also does not appear to worsen from **anything else** in my code, so besides it being a terribly ugly bug, my conclusion is that it's **A OK.**

Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find sporadic leaks that Xcode Instruments flags as such, but I cannot do anything about it, because the problem is in Apple's code, which is apparently your case. The only thing you can do is to **file a bug report** and go on with your project, in particular if the leak is **sporadic**, and is only a question of a few bytes, and **does not build up in time**. In summary, if these conditions apply, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822434/ios-keyboard-extension-memory-crash it seems that each time the keyboard is presented it "adds" a new controller, incrementing each time without properly releasing the previous instance. Absolutely ridiculous.